# No inserta registro en base de datos MySQL con PHP mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, php7

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es insertar por una consulta preparada de PHP, los datos de un formulario en una base de datos MySQL. Con el método de conexión orientado a objetos mysqli. 
Aquí está el código de la clase "connection.php".

```
<?php
class Connection extends mysqli{
  //Connection data
  private $DB_NAME = "datos";
  private $DB_TABLE = "user";
  private $DB_HOST = "localhost";
  private $DB_PASSWORD = "password";
  private $DB_USER = "root";
  public $DB_CHARSET = "utf8";

  //Constructor
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct($this->DB_HOST,$this->DB_USER,$this->DB_PASSWORD,$this->DB_NAME);
    if ($this->connect_errno) echo "<div class='mensaje'>Error:
      {$this->connect_errno} -> {$this->connect_error}</div>";
    $this->set_charset($this->DB_CHARSET);
  }

  //Insert new record
  public function insert($id,$name,$password){
    $sql_comand = "INSERT INTO {$this->DB_TABLE} VALUES (?,?,?)";
    if(!($sentence = $this->prepare($sql_comand))){
      echo "Error(prepare): {$this->connect_errno} -> {$this->connect_error}";
    }
    $sentence = $this->bind_param("iss",$id,$name,$password);
    $sentence->execute();
    $sentence->close();
  }

}
?>
```

Y este es el código principal "index.php".

```
<form action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="number" class="id" name="id" maxlength="11" placeholder="ID"><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="35" placeholder="Name"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="60" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
  require "connection.php";

  if(isset($_POST["button"])){
    $con = new Connection();
    $id = htmlspecialchars($_POST["id"]);
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);
    $con->insert($id,$name,$password);
    $con->close();
  }
?>
```

Después de revisar y revisar decenas de veces, no he podido hallar la causa del porqué no se ha podido hacer exitosamente la inserción de los datos del formulario a la base de datos MySQL.

Comment: ¿Que error es el que obtienes?

Comment: No me sale ningun error

Answer (score 0):

Te debería arrojar un error `"Call to undefined method Connection::bind_param()"` ya que tienes un un error en el bind_param:

La sentencia debería ser :

```
//Insert new record
  public function insert($id,$name,$password){
    $sql_comand = "INSERT INTO {$this->DB_TABLE} VALUES (?,?,?)";
    if(!($sentence = $this->prepare($sql_comand))){
      echo "Error(prepare): {$this->connect_errno} -> {$this->connect_error}";
    }
    $sentence = bind_param("iss",$id,$name,$password);
    $sentence->execute();
    $sentence->close();
  }
```

Es decir debes cambiar esto:

```
$sentence = $this->bind_param("iss",$id,$name,$password);
```

Por esto

```
$sentence = bind_param("iss",$id,$name,$password);
```

Y te va a funcionar. Como recomendación cuando trabajes en desarrollo activa el despliegue de errores en tiempo de ejecución, ya sea vía servidor o vía código:

```
// Mostrar todos los errores de PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```